# Nginx not sending auth headers when redirecting to a different domain

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have the following setup:

```
server {
    server_name some.server;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://otherserver.com permanent;
    }
 }
```

The redirect works as expected, but the `Authorization` headers sent to the first request are not sent to the otherserver. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP authentication is domain-based, if the browser kept sending `Authorization` headers after a redirect to another domain then it would be leaking user credentials. If you need cross-domain authentication you should use some other technique.

Comment: That's mostly true, but you can put the base64-decoded (and subsequently URL-encoded) value of the `Authorization` header in the URL for the `Location` response header used for redirection.  `http://user:pass@example.com`  I just can't find a good way to do this conditionally in an Nginx config file.